# How to implement this operation in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

Suppose we have two tensors X,Y of shapes, say, (a,b) and (b,c) respectively. We can then construct a new tensor T of shape (a,b,c) defined by `T[i][j][k] = X[i][j] + Y[j][k]`.

How can I implement this in TensorFlow? How about the analogue where I replace the addition with multiplication?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
a = tf.constant([[2,3],[4,1]]) # A 2x2 matrix
b = tf.constant([[1,2,1],[3,4,2]]) # A 2x3 matrix

# Make a into 2x2x3 matrix
aa = tf.expand_dims(a,-1)
# Make b into 1x2x3 matrix
bb = tf.expand_dims(b, 0)

# Do element wise addition, resulting in 2x2x3 matrix.
c = aa + bb
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. One question: why do you have to repeat a? Doesn't the broadcasting take care of it?

Comment: @user11267981 Yeah that should be fine actually. I didn't realize it at the time.